# dynamic dropdown menu switching direction

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I have a dynamic dropdown menu using jQuery where the number of main navigation links are dependent on a CMS. Is there way to make it so if the dropdown container touches the wrapper of the website then it flips sides and is right aligned so there is no overflow outside of the main webpage container?  See http://online.wsj.com/home-page as an example.

**EDIT**

Here is th code.

```
<script>
$("ul#navBar li span").click(function() { //When trigger is clicked...
        //caching selectors
        var $this = $(this),
        $parent = $this.parent(),
        $siblings = $parent.siblings(),
        $dropdowns_siblings = $siblings.find('.dropdown');

        $this.next().toggle(); //toggles the dropdown on click

        //hide other menus if visible
        $dropdowns_siblings.hide();


        function rowWidth(){    
            //Calculate width of ul
            var rowWidth = 0;       
            $parent.find("ul").each(function() {rowWidth += $(this).width(); });    

            //Set width of .dropdown
            $parent.find(".dropdown").css({'width' : rowWidth});
            };
        return rowWidth();
</script>

<div id="container">
 <ul id="navBar">
    <li><a href="/">Link 1</a> <span></span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            dynamic # of cols
        </div>
    </li>
<li><a href="/">Link 1</a> <span></span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            dynamic # of cols
        </div>
    </li>
<li><a href="/">Link 1</a> <span></span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            dynamic # of cols
        </div>
    </li>
<li><a href="/">Link 1</a> <span></span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            dynamic # of cols
        </div>
    </li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Uh, did you forget to check my response again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.fn.offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset) and compare to see if `jQuery(window).width()` is more than the sum of the `left` component of that offset and the width of your menu, and if it's not and the menu is cropped, then update the positioning of the menu to align itself with the other edge of the button (or menu trigger), etc. You'd bind this function to fire when the window gets [resized](http://api.jquery.com/resize) or if there is horizontal [scrolling](http://api.jquery.com/scroll). Sorry if this is too high-level and not enough example code, but it should be enough to get you started.

...

I've solved your problem with [an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hlfcoding/urZ7Z/). I think it's what you're looking for. I've filled in a lot of missing CSS from your original code, with some non-IE CSS selectors to save time. I also rewrote most of the js. There is definitely room for refinement, but it works well. I also didn't bind it to adjust live when the window is resizing, but I think that's more of an edge case compared to the click bindings.

Comment: Yeah that went over my head. I've added my code if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Also how would you make it if the user clicks anywhere else outside that the drop down would disappear?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not here to do your work for you. I answered your question and even provided an example. Even though I can write it quickly, you should learn jQuery on your own if you want that functionality. And if my answer is sufficient you should accept it as answer.